# Why is my Depth First Search Implementation Broken

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I've been experimenting with different ways of implementing depth first search. I've found a few working ways, but they involved some rather tedious dictionary work. I've developed a new idea using lists, but the actions this implementation returns don't match the desired result. I'll try to comment the code as clearly as I can:

```
start = problem.getStartState()            ## returns an (x, y) tuple
children = problem.getSuccessors(start)    ##returns the children of a parent node in ((start                  
                                           state), action, cost) format. 
stack = Stack()                            ##creates a Stack (LIFO) data structure
visited = []                               ##list of visited nodes
visited.append(start)
for child in children:
    stack.push((child, [], [], 0))         ##push children to fringe in the format of (child,
    while stack:                           ##path taken, actions taken, cost) 
        parent = stack.pop()
        node = parent[0]
        if parent[0] in visited: continue
        visited.append(parent[0])
        path = parent[1] + [node[0]]           ##assigns previous path/actions/cost to new 
        actions = parent[2] + [node[1]]        ##node, creating a cumulative, ordered list of
        print actions                          ##the path/actions and a cumulative cost
        cost = parent[3] + node[2]
        if problem.isGoalState(node[0]):
            print parent[2]
            return parent[2]                    ## returns list of actions 
        children = problem.getSuccessors(node[0])
        if children != []:
            for child in children:
                stack.push((child, path, actions, cost))   ##assigns cumulative lists to child
```

Anyone see where my problems might lie in this implementation? BTW, I know DFS is an inefficient algorithm for most cases. But once I get this implementation right, it should be able to cross over to other search algorithms by simply changing the data structure that stores the children of the parent node.

Comment: Can you give an example of expected output vs your output?

Comment: You have a code smell where you treat the "start" node differently then the other nodes when iterating its children. I'm betting the bug is connected to this.

Comment: Well, it's very problem specific and probably wouldn't make too much sense without a ton of specifications. Basically, I am expecting a list of actions that will lead me on the correct path to the goal destination. The problem reaches the goal destination (otherwise it would return nothing), but the list of actions somehow has me backtracking over already covered ground (despite my visited list) and stopping at a dead end.

Comment: Can you add some debugging symbols ? For example on the graph provided here : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576723-dfs-and-bfs-graph-traversal/ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CS188 pal :D It's really hard to read your code here... all those indexes %)
Use more variables and it'll be more clear.
My solution:

```
def depthFirstSearch(problem):
    fringe = util.Stack()
    expanded = set()
    fringe.push((problem.getStartState(),[],0))
    
    while not fringe.isEmpty():
        curState, curMoves, curCost = fringe.pop()
        
        if(curState in expanded):
            continue
        
        expanded.add(curState)
        
        if problem.isGoalState(curState):
            return curMoves
        
        for state, direction, cost in problem.getSuccessors(curState):
            fringe.push((state, curMoves+[direction], curCost))
    return []
```

I hope I don't need to comment it. It's easy to read :)
Have a good day ;)

Comment: While it works (in principle didn't test), it does not answer the question: `Anyone see where my problems might lie in this implementation?`

Comment: note that it's generally considered bad style in Python to put unnecessary semicolons.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just used to use C/C++/C# most of my coding time :)     amit, you have a lot of mistakes in your code. I think it'd take more than hour to find them all :) At least your first for loop violates order of visited nodes. You can use Eclipse + PyDev to debug your code.

Comment: @parkee: It is not *my* code, I am just a commenter. It still does not answer the question.

Comment: While it doesn't directly answer the question, it is exactly what I'm looking for. Granted, parkee has an advantage over other responders by virtue of being in the open online course that this code was written for. This solution is the best I've seen thus far for this problem set... One question that I keep coming back to that maybe you can answer... why is it that a set is so much more preferable than a list for the "expanded" closed set?

Comment: @user1427661: checking for membership in a set is O(1), while checking for membership in a list is O(n).

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a name clash. Note that:

```
children = problem.getSuccessors(start)    ##returns the children of a parent node in ((start                  
... 
for child in children:
    ...
    while stack:
        ...
        children = problem.getSuccessors(node[0])
        ...
```

after the first iteration, your original children is lost since it's overwritten by the children in the inner loop.

Generally, DFS is best implemented using [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29), roughly like the following (untested):

```
def dfs(problem, state, visited):
    visited.append(state)

    # have we reached the goal?
    if problem.isGoalState(state):
        return [state]

    for child in problem.getSuccessors(state):
        # if child is already visited, don't bother with it
        if child in visited: continue

        # otherwise, visit the child
        ret = dfs(problem, child, visited)

        if ret is not None:
            # goal state has been reached, accumulate the states
            ret.append(state)
            return ret

    return None # failed to find solution here
    # note that Python return None by default when reaching the end of a function
```

Comment: +1: Both pointing the problem and offering a more elegant alternative.

Comment: Good answer. Might the relatively high overhead for function calls be a concern though? Or, for large data structures, what about the recursion limit? Is it just that these are usually negligible and unlikely to be reached, respectively?